# Mixing numerical Regex with egrep?

Tags: grep

I am lite bit confused here egrep "^[0-9]+ < [0-9]{1,3}$". I know that :
 ^[0-9]  wherever it starts with number. But what does + < and {1,3}mean here?

Answer (score 0):

For `+`, this will mean one or more matches.

For `{1,3}` it means 1 to 3 times for matching.